# the truth of proposition logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

For proposition A "I work" , B "I study " C "I passed math exam"

State the validity of the reasoning

1.I'm not studying if I work

２.I work or pass the math exam

３.I I passed the math exam. So I studied

1.$A \implies \sim B$

2.$A \lor C$

3.$C \implies B$

$C \implies B$ also means $\sim B \implies \sim C$ ,

$A \implies \sim B \implies \sim C$

$A \implies\sim C$= $\sim A \lor \sim C$

is this enough to proof?

Comment: 3 is translated incorrectly. Statement 3 just asserts that you passed the exam, not that "if you pass the exam then you studied". So 3 should not be $C\implies B$, unless the written statement of 3 is given incomplete here.  Second: you don't give a "reasoning"; you only gave three premises, but do not state what the asserted conclusion is supposed to be. Are you presenting the full problem correctly?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm sorry i wrote incomplete statement for third one , it supposed to be "I passed the math exam. So I studied" . The problem only state three of the condition, and i need to find the the validity of reasoning

Comment: I don't think you are parsing this right. I seems to me that the three premises are supposed to be: (1) I'm not studying if I work; (2) I work or pass the exam; and (3) I passed the exam. And the **conclusion** of the reasoning is supposed to be "I studied". You are trying to verify if (1), (2), and (3) imply "I studied". Because if all you have are three statements, then *you do not have any "reasoning" to validate*. Does that seem possible? That you are misinterpreting what you are given?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ok maybe i was wrong when parsing the problem. if the problem are (1) I'm not studying if I work; (2) I work or pass the exam; and (3) I passed the exam. . how can you conlude that " I studied"?

Comment: You can't; it's possible for "I work" and "I pass the exam" to be true, "I'm studying" to be false. Then (1) holds, (2) holds, (3) holds, but "I studied" does not. That would be an invalid reasoning.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ok so we cannot conclude anything from the premise, or we can conclude that "I'm  studied" is False?

Comment: An argument is unsound if it is possible for the premises to be true and the conclusion to be false; here, the argument is unsound. Moreover, you *also* cannot conclude that the conclusion *must* be false, since making all three statements true will also give you a situation where the three premises hold. So the premises do not allow you to conclude *either* that "I studiet*, **nor** that "I did not study".